# Categorical coproduct

Tags: category-theory

I would like to get some hints to help me to understand (one specific) definition of coproducts in category theory. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of objects, now my notes says that a coproduct of the $(X_i)$ is an ordered pair $(X,(\mathfrak{i}_i)_{i\in I})$, where the $\mathfrak{i}_i=X_i\to X$ if for each test object $Y\in \mathcal{C}$ the map

$$Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \stackrel {Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathfrak{i}_i,-)}\longrightarrow \prod_{i\in I}Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X_i,Y) $$

is bijective.

Now, I have some problems with the nature of $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathfrak{i}_i,-)$, and how does the product looks like? I mean a product of morphisms. Thank you for any help

Comment: You don't mean a product of morphisms; you mean a product of sets of morphisms.

Comment: Like a tuple $(f_i)_{i\in I}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct#Discussion

Comment: getting clearer, I see, thanks.

Comment: and what is the "-" in Hom(i,-)?

Comment: Not clear to me the notation. I want to understand it as a placeholder for any $f\in Hom_{\cal C}(X,Y)$, in the sense that $f_i=f\circ i_i$.

Comment: Yes, $Hom(i_i,-)$ sends a morphism $f:X\to Y$ to $f\circ i_i: X_i\to Y$.